# Header font inconsistency

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

`#Headers#` in suggested edits use `font-family: 'PFTempestaSevenRegular', sans-serif;` while on the main page they inherit `font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;`.

Could they both use one or the other?

**Main page**

[image]

**Suggested edits review**

[image]